# Starting postgresql 10 from mounted drive

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I have *Ubuntu 18.04* with boot disk of 30 GB(VM_A) and there was mounted drive(4TB) to it from another machine. due to a recent restart the mounted drive was unmounted then i had to mount that drive to VM_A in `media/mounted_drive` 4TB dir. Now this mounted drive had *Postgresql 10* running fine which is not running after re-mount. Followings lines i have altered to start postgres in `postgresql.conf` file.

```
/media/mounted_drive/etc/postgresql/10/main
/media/mounted_drive/etc/postgresql/10/pg_hba.conf
/media/mounted_drive/etc/postgresql/10/pg_ident.conf
/media/mounted_drive//var/run/postgresql/10-main.pid
```

but still it fails to start

[image: Postgres_service]

and i'm not able to locate the `postgres.service` file also

[image: postgres.service]

What all changes i'll have to make to start postgres.

Note: If this already answered point me to the right one.

Comment: Where was it mounted before the restart? `/etc`? Also, there is an extra slash in the last line of your `postgreqsl.conf` file.

Comment: The devs don't have clear idea where exactly was it mounted so not sure. Changed the extra slash.

Comment: Didn't got much time to restored to snapshot of 4TB and discarded 30gb, Hope fully it'll not break again.